# my simple drag & drop function stutters

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

This is a pretty basic function I made to make some elements draggable with the mouse.

```
$('.draggable').on('mousedown', function(e) {   
  var start = { top : parseInt($(this).css('top').replace(/px/,'')),
  left: parseInt($(this).css('left').replace(/px/,''))  };
  var mouse = { top : e.clientY, left: e.clientX };

  $(this).addClass('dragged').on('mousemove',function(e) {
        var end = {Y:start.top  + e.clientY - mouse.top,
               X:start.left + e.clientX - mouse.left }

  $(this).css({top: end.Y+'px', left: end.X+'px'}); 

  }).on('mouseup, mouseout, click',function() {
     $(this).removeClass('dragged').off('mousemove');
    });
    return false;
});
```

It works, the problem is the "**animation**" stutters and is slow. it can't keep up with the mouse speed and the mouseup event isn't fired correctly (I need to click again on the element to release it).

How could it be improved?
**I'd like to keep it simple & stupid**, so I'm not going to use some bloated script I can barely understand, and I'm not going to use JQueryUI.

EDIT:  thanks to rgthree, and with a little adjustment, this now works!

```
    $('.draggable').on('mousedown', function(e) {
            var start = {   top : parseInt($(this).css('top').replace(/px/,'')),
                            left: parseInt($(this).css('left').replace(/px/,''))    };
            var mouse = {   top : e.clientY,
                            left: e.clientX     };
            var element = this;

            $(this).addClass('dragged');
            $(window).on('mousemove',function(mme) {
                var end = { Y:  start.top  + mme.clientY - mouse.top,
                            X:  start.left + mme.clientX - mouse.left   }

                $(element).css({    top : end.Y+'px',
                                left: end.X+'px'    });
            });
        }).on('mouseup',function() {
            $(this).removeClass('dragged');
            $(window).off('mousemove');
        });
```

Comment: It's your call boss,but why not to use jQuery UI?

Comment: because i don't think i need a 100K script just to accomplish this simple task

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, your problem stems primarily from your `mousemove` method. Because it's listening on your drag element, when you move too quickly your mouse has the tendency to move off your element and, thus, it stop responding. Instead, listen for mousemove on the `window`. I don't use jQuery so I'm not double-checking the rest of your work, but I believe this is what you want (and it works fine in this fiddle): http://jsfiddle.net/rgthree/dqPtV/

```
$('#tvsel .tavoli').on('mousedown', function(e) {
    var start = {
        top:parseInt($(this).css('top').replace(/px/,'')),
        left: parseInt($(this).css('left').replace(/px/,''))
    };
    var mouse = {top:e.clientY, left:e.clientX};
    var el = $(this);
    el.addClass('dragged');
    $(window).on('mousemove',function(mme) {
        var end = {
            Y:start.top + mme.clientY - mouse.top,
            X:start.left + mme.clientX - mouse.left
        }
        el.css({top:end.Y+'px', left:end.X+'px'});
    }).on('mouseup, mouseout, click',function() {
        el.removeClass('dragged');
        $(window).off('mousemove');
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In cases where calculations (or ajax requests or redraws or whatever) are too slow, you could *throttle* the function to execute it only once every `interval`. There is a library written for this, [Ben Alman's throttle/debounce](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/) - and don't worry, it's 0.7 kilobyte =)

> jQuery throttle / debounce allows you to rate-limit your functions in multiple useful ways. Passing a delay and callback to $.throttle returns a new function that will execute no more than once every delay milliseconds.

In your case, throttle the callback for `mousemove`.

```
// Choose an interval that keeps the movement smooth
var interval = 10;

$(window)
  .on('mousemove', $.throttle(interval, function(e)
  {
    // Your move function
  }));
```

Using `$(window)` as suggested by @rgthree.

Comment: great advice! i was actually thinking about putting a timeout somewhere, but when i tried it broke the code, so i didn't bother finding a solution.
thank you